# Redirect the php with user-agent

Tags: php, user-agent

What i want to do is to make a php file in order to redirect the page if the user-agent of the browser it's not equal to my custom user-agent. Here is my code but is not working

```
<?php

$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if( strpos($useragent,"MyCustomUserAgent") ) {

  header("Location: http://google.com/");

}
?>
```

Comment: *but is not working* What does it do? What results do you expect and what results do you receive? Can you add more details please?

Answer (score 0):

A problem I immediately see is that you are not evaluating this as strict.

[From php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the
>   beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note
>   that string positions start at 0, and not 1.

Next, your if should be inverted. You want to redirect if it is **NOT** your useragent.

```
<?php

$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if (strpos($useragent, "MyCustomUserAgent") === false) {

  header("Location: http://google.com/");

} ?>
```

Comment: Not saying that this isn't correct, but we should wait for the OP to actually explain the issue before we give an answer. No error description === off-topic === should not be answered.

Comment: @Emiljan Remember to accept an answer if it answered your question.